# missing 2 required positional arguments: 'user_name' and 'password' when processing POST REST API call

Tags: python, rest, yaml, swagger

I got TypeError: sessions_post() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'user_name' and 'password' in the python controller when processing the POST REST API call, the POST call has 'user_name' and 'password' defined in the http header, see below YAML file:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '0.0.1'
  title: sessions
  #description: To be provided
  #  #termsOfService:To be provided
  contact:
   name: test

paths:
  /sessions:
    post:
      summary: eatablish a session
      description: sessions is a collection.This POST creates a new session in the sessions collection and the name of the session returned by this command is the session token.
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: user_name
          type: string
          required: true
        - in: header
          name: password
          type: string
          required: true          
      responses:
        200:
          description: establish a session successfully
        400:
          $ref: "#/responses/BadRequest"
        500:
          description: unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/errorModel'
```

Below is my python controller side code:

```
def sessions_post(user_name, password):
    token = sessions_helper.authenticate(user_name, password)
    return 'do some magic!'
```

Below is the curl request:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://localhost/sessions" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "user_name: admin" -H  "password: admin" -d ""
```

Do I miss any configuration thing for the http header 'user_name' and 'password'? Thanks.